# Training loss is decreasing but validation loss is not

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to do semantic segmentation on skin lesion. I used SegNet as my model. But after running this model, training loss was decreasing but validation loss was not decreasing. i.e. overfitting problem is occured. I tuned learning rate many times and reduced number of number dense layer but no solution came. I also used dropout but still overfitting is happening.
[Here is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2hjj.png)

Here is the code of my model:
def segnet(input_size=(512, 512, 1)):

```
# Encoding layer
img_input = Input(input_size)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv1',strides= (1,1))(img_input)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn1')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn2')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv3')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn3')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv4')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn4')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)


x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv5')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn5')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv6')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn6')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv7')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn7')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv8')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn8')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv9')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn9')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv10')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn10')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv11')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn11')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv12')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn12')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='conv13')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn13')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

x = Dense(256, activation = 'relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(256, activation = 'relu', name='fc2')(x)
# Decoding Layer 
x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv1')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn14')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn15')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv3')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn16')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv4')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn17')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(512, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv5')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn18')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv6')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn19')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv7')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn20')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(256, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv8')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn21')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv9')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn22')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv10')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn23')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv11')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn24')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)

x = UpSampling2D()(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv12')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn25')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), padding='same', name='deconv13')(x)
x = BatchNormalization(name='bn26')(x)
x = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
pred = Reshape((input_size[0], input_size[1]))(x)

return Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=pred)
```

I have used the same dataset for another modle UNet but there was no overfit for UNet. This is giving overfit only for SegNet model.
For more information :
model = segnet(input_size = (224, 224, INPUT_CHANNELS))

```
model.compile(optimizer= Adam(lr=1e-5), loss= [dice_coef_loss]
          , metrics=[iou, dice_coe, precision, recall, accuracy])

model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(str(j+1) + '_skin_leison.hdf5', 
                                   monitor='loss', 
                                   verbose=1, 
                                   save_best_only=True)

callbacks_list = [model_checkpoint]
history = model.fit(X_train_cv,
                 y_train_cv,
                 epochs= 70,
                 callbacks = callbacks_list,
                 batch_size= 8,
                 validation_data=(X_valid_cv, y_valid_cv))
```

Comment: It may be about dropout levels. Try to drop your dropout level. Use 0.3-0.5 for the first layer and less for the next layers. The other thing came into my mind is shuffling your data before train validation split. One last thing, try stride=(2,2)

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work. Thank you for giving me suggestions.

Comment: We need information about your dataset, what kind of data this is, how many example in which split, how did you divide it, do you have any data augmentations? You are able to overfit the network, which is a pretty good predictor of successful network implementation.

Comment: This is image data taken from kaggle. There are total 200 images and i used 5-fold cross validation. I augmented the data by rotating and flipping.

Comment: Try data augmentation and shuffling the data this should give you a better result.